# UIDocumentPickerViewController doesn't show any contents on Mac Catalyst

Tags: swiftui, mac-catalyst

UIDocumentPickerViewController works on iOS but not on Mac Catalyst. Is there any alternatives to workaround this issue? BTW, NSOpenPanel is unavailable on Mac Catalyst.

[image]

Comment: I'm also having this issue. I haven't found a workaround yet...

Comment: Did you guys find a fix for this?

Comment: I used builtin UIDocumentPickerViewController but I had only assigned Read access to User Selected files which allowed to open pick dialog. Then I updated permission to Read/Write to actually make it work.

Answer (score 4):

There's extra code in @UnchartedWorks' excellent answer. Here's a cleaner version with some options, more copy/paste-able into your code. This works on iOS, iPadOS, and Mac Catalyst (without using a #if conditional).

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import MobileCoreServices

/// A wrapper for a UIDocumentPickerViewController that acts as a delegate and passes the selected file to a callback
///
/// DocumentPicker also sets allowsMultipleSelection to `false`.
final class DocumentPicker: NSObject {

    /// The types of documents to show in the picker
    let types: [String]

    /// The callback to call with the selected document URLs
    let callback: ([URL]) -> ()

    /// Should the user be allowed to select more than one item?
    let allowsMultipleSelection: Bool

    /// Creates a DocumentPicker, defaulting to selecting folders and allowing only one selection
    init(for types: [String] = [String(kUTTypeFolder)],
         allowsMultipleSelection: Bool = false,
         _ callback: @escaping ([URL]) -> () = { _ in }) {
        self.types = types
        self.allowsMultipleSelection = allowsMultipleSelection
        self.callback = callback
    }

    /// Returns the view controller that must be presented to display the picker
    lazy var viewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController = {
        let vc = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: types, in: .open)
        vc.delegate = self
        vc.allowsMultipleSelection = self.allowsMultipleSelection
        return vc
    }()

}

extension DocumentPicker: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    /// Delegate method that's called when the user selects one or more documents or folders
    ///
    /// This method calls the provided callback with the URLs of the selected documents or folders.
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        callback(urls)
    }

    /// Delegate method that's called when the user cancels or otherwise dismisses the picker
    ///
    /// Does nothing but close the picker.
    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("cancelled")
    }
}
```

IMPORTANT: Add the "com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write" (Boolean, set to YES) entitlement to your app's entitlements file or it will crash when you open the picker on the Mac. If you only need read access, you can use "com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read" instead.

Sample usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    /// The view controller for the sheet that lets the user select the project support folder
    ///
    /// Yes, I said "view controller" - we need to go old school for Catalyst and present a view controller from the root view controller manually.
    @State var filePicker: DocumentPicker

    init() {
        // Setting filePicker like this lets us keep DocumentPicker in the view
        // layer (instead of a model or view model), lets SwiftUI hang onto
        // the reference to it, and lets you specify another function to
        // call (e.g. one from a view model) using info passed into your
        // init method.
        _filePicker = State(initialValue: DocumentPicker({urls in
                print(urls)
            }))
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button("Pick a folder") {
            self.presentDocumentPicker()
        }
    }

    /// Presents the document picker from the root view controller
    ///
    /// This is required on Catalyst but works on iOS and iPadOS too, so we do it this way instead of in a UIViewControllerRepresentable
    func presentDocumentPicker() {
        let viewController = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController!
        let controller = self.filePicker.viewController
        viewController.present(controller, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Worth noting that the `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write` right was not added to my entitlements file even when I selected "User Selected File: Read only" on the Xcode GUI. Adding it manually resolved the issue. (Xcode 14.2)

Answer (score 2):

[image: screenshot]
The following example is for Mac Catalyst. If you want to support UIDocumentPickerViewController on iOS and Mac Catalyst, you should use

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
//code for Mac Catalyst
#endif
```

How to support UIDocumentPickerViewController on Mac Catalyst

```
//SceneDelegate.swift
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var picker = DocumentPicker()

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    let contentView = ContentView()
        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()

            window.rootViewController?.present(picker.viewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}


//ContentView.swift
final class DocumentPicker: NSObject, UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIDocumentPickerViewController

    lazy var viewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController = {
        let vc = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.data"], in: .open)
        vc.delegate = self
        return vc
    }()

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
        viewController.delegate = self
        return viewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) {
    }
}

extension DocumentPicker: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        print(urls)
    }

    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("cancelled")
    }
}
```

Thanks for Simon, without his help, I can't solve this issue.

Comment: This does not work. See my question for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078623/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller-in-swiftui-on-mac-maccatalyst

Comment: Works fine in iOS not in MacOs. And reading comments it looks to be from Catalina. And Swift UI is also unstable on alerts, .contextMenu in MacOS gives "not a known serializable element and returning it as an accessibility element may lead to crashes". Question is what to do about it? The alert and context menues can be handmade. But picking open a file (UIDocumentPickerViewController) and saving (UIApplication) do not react in MacOS and is far harder to be handmade? Is there a soon solution by upgrade from Apple, any good work around or shall we expect to make a handmade solution? Any hints?

Comment: Also I think it is sad we don't have a catalyst file picker and document saver/sender (it is fatal without). The Catalyst Mac program (Mac program with a style alike iOS) looks in fact very good. The SwiftUI for Catalyst is far easier to look good than SwiftUI for Mac only. Also Mac users are in general with very few exceptions iOS users and not just accept but will appreciate and rather expect a development of Mac programs into a slight iOS style, meaning it has a commercial value. _The Catalyst is a very good development if we just got the picker and the saver/sender. It is worth efforts._

Comment: Yes, you have to use Catalina. I agree with you, Apple should support this feature.

Comment: Note that you'll need to add the "com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write" (Boolean, set to YES) entitlement to your app's entitlements file or it will crash when you open the picker (e.g. if you copy/paste this code into a new Xcode project and run it).

Answer (score 2):

You have to go to your Target -> Signing & Capabilities and set the File access.

Comment: don't comments on answer section.

Comment: I used builtin UIDocumentPickerViewController but I had only assigned Read access to User Selected files which allowed to open pick dialog. Then I updated permission to Read/Write to actually make it work.

Answer (score 1):

After many attempts, I managed to find the code below that works well with Xcode 11.3.1 on Mac Catalyst.

```
import SwiftUI

    final class DocumentPicker: NSObject, UIViewControllerRepresentable, ObservableObject {
        typealias UIViewControllerType = UIDocumentPickerViewController
        @Published var urlsPicked = [URL]()

        lazy var viewController:UIDocumentPickerViewController = {
            // For picked only folder
            let vc = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.folder"], in: .open)
            // For picked every document
    //        let vc = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.data"], in: .open)
            // For picked only images
    //        let vc = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.image"], in: .open)
            vc.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    //        vc.accessibilityElements = [kFolderActionCode]
    //        vc.shouldShowFileExtensions = true
            vc.delegate = self
            return vc
        }()

        func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
            viewController.delegate = self
            return viewController
        }

        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) {
        }
    }

    extension DocumentPicker: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
        func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
            urlsPicked = urls
            print("DocumentPicker geoFolder.geoFolderPath: \(urlsPicked[0].path)")
        }

    //    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
    //        controller.dismiss(animated: true) {
    //        }
    //    }
    }
```

and I use the code above, for example with:

```
import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView: View {
        @ObservedObject var picker = DocumentPicker()
        @State private var urlPick = ""

        var body: some View {
                HStack {
                    urlPickedFoRTextField()
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
                        let viewController = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController!
                        viewController.present(self.picker.viewController, animated: true)
                        self.picker.objectWillChange.send()
                        #endif
                        print("Hai premuto il pulsante per determinare il path della GeoFolder")
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                    }
                }
                .padding()
        }

        private func urlPickedFoRTextField() -> some View {
            if picker.urlsPicked.count > 0 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.urlPick = self.picker.urlsPicked[0].path
                }
            }
            return TextField("", text: $urlPick)
        }
    }
```

I hope I was helpful.