# UIDocumentPickerViewController in SwiftUI on mac (macCatalyst)

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, mac-catalyst

So I've been meddling with "moving" a small SwiftUI iPad app to the Mac, and I've hit a bit of a speed bump with `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.
I have wrapped the `UIDocumentPickerViewController` in a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` like so :

```
struct DocumentPickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
    let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [(kUTTypeImage as String)], in: .import)
    return documentPicker
  }

  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: Context) {

  }
}
```

**And displaying it like this:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var shows = false
var body: some View {
    Button(action: { self.shows.toggle() }) {
        Text("Select File")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: self.$shows) {
        DocumentPickerView()
    }
  }
}
```

**On the iPad all is working well,** 
[image: iPad]

But when on on the Mac, the `UIDocumentPickerViewController`doesnt show and we get this blank modal:

[image: Mac]

Comment: Well if I use UIKit with Catalyst, it opens a macos file picker. When using SwiftUI, with catalyst, i get the blank view. I would expect the same behaviour for SwiftUI.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue. It shows as you are expecting here. I run into another issue selecting a file though. It does nothing and log error: `Failed to create an FPSandboxingURLWrapper for file ... Error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "couldn't issue sandbox extension com.apple.app-sandbox.read-write for '/..fileName': Operation not permitted" UserInfo={NSDescription=couldn't issue sandbox extension com.apple.app-sandbox.read-write for '/../fileName.png': Operation not permitted}`. Using `UIDocumentBrowserViewController`instead fixes my issue.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. This has to be a bug in SwiftUI. It should really transform the UIDocumentPickerViewController into an NSOpenPanel on macOS. Bug for sure!

Comment: @shallowThought for some reason you need to select read &write permission for user selectedDocument. Also documentBrowser i think is intended for something else

Comment: Well, if you don't have read permissions outside the sandbox it's impossible to pick an arbitrary file selected by the user... but that's not the problem. The problem is that UIDocumentPickerViewController should show an NSOpenPanel when running on macOS. It works if using UIKit, but it doesn't work with SwiftUI. @ALexPopa is correct in his observation.

Comment: I just filed a bug report through the Feedback Assistant app...

Comment: Great! Let’s hope they fix it soon.

Comment: If you are working with a Document-based app as I'm doing you can work around the problem by letting the UIDocumentBrowserViewController present the dialog. It's a pain... but at least it works ;-)

Comment: `let controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController(url: tempURL, in: .moveToService)
                controller.delegate = self
                if let presentedViewController = self.presentedViewController {
                    // let the ContentView present the
                    self.modalSelection = .save
                    presentedViewController.present(controller, animated: true)
                }`

Comment: Another way i found to work around it, is to grab the rootViewController off the keyWindow, and present the the UIDocumentPickerViewController from there

Comment: @shallowThought could you provide working code? With picker or browser.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced deprecated method and enabled asked entitlement for provided topic starter code and it works.

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / macOS 12.2

```
import UniformTypeIdentifiers
struct DocumentPickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
    let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [UTType.image], asCopy: true)
    return documentPicker
  }

  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: Context) {

  }
}
```

[image: config]

and demo opening standard macOS picker

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For some reason (I'm not aware of further specific details), the following worked for me (for Catalyst):

Instead of using `in: .import`

```
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(
    documentTypes: [(kUTTypeImage as String)], 
    in: .import
)
```

Use `in: .open`

```
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(
    documentTypes: [(kUTTypeImage as String)], 
    in: .open
)
```

I haven't checked if the functionality is maintained in iOS, but perhaps you can use some sort of "flag" to  determine wether to use `.import` or `.open`