# Swift • UIDocumentPicker works on iOS & iPadOS but not on the Mac Catalyst Version

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I am developing an `SwiftUI iOS App` for iPhone & iPad. The App also utilizes `Mac Catalyst` to port the Version to the Mac.

**Problem:** I implemented a UIDocumentPicker *(UIViewControllerRepresentable)* which works great on iPhone & iPad. On the Mac, a Finder-Window appears and I can select a File, however, the file does not get processed by the app then.

**Research:** I tested my code a bit and discovered, that `documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL])` does **not** get called on the `Mac Catalyst` Version, while getting called on the `iOS / iPadOS` Version.

**Code**

```swift
struct DocumentPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var show: Bool
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return DocumentPicker.Coordinator(documentPicker: self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIDocumentPickerViewController {
        let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.pdf], asCopy: true)
        documentPicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = false

        return documentPicker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) {
        // ...
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {

        var documentPicker: DocumentPicker

        init(documentPicker: DocumentPicker) { self.documentPicker = documentPicker }
        
        func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {

            print("File selected") // Does not get called on macOS.
  
            // Check whether there is a valid URL.
            guard let safeFilePath = urls.first else { return }
       
            // Check whether a File exists at the given URL
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: safeFilePath.path) {
  
                // Save as Data.
                let data = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: safeFilePath.path)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:** Why does the `DocumentPicker` not work on `macOS` but on iOS?

Comment: have you check? : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62225520/14733292

Comment: @RajaKishan thanks for your answer, but I already found this question and it didn't help. In my case, the document picker does appear, however, the `didPickDocumentsAt` delegate-method does not get called on macOS

Answer (score 2):

When you create `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, use `asCopy: false`.